# Antlr - Control Flow Graph

Tags: java, eclipse, antlr, analysis, control-flow

Is it possible to build a control flow graph for a Java program using Antlr? Are there any resources out there that provide guidelines on doing so? Is there a better approach than using Antlr or are there any kind of eclipse tools that might help?

Comment: What is your definition of a "Java program"? I'm sure there are tools that do this for a (small) Java class, but I doubt it will handle complete Java applications.

Comment: These graphs are frequently used to visualize an algorithm (a small section of code), and because for moderately large Java app, the graph would become rather large (huge would be a better word), and I therefor think there's no tool that produces a complete CFG given an arbitrary large Java application. But, you might want to specify what your definition of a "Java program" is.

Comment: I didn't know that. Well the java program I would refer to would be a program that streams video from a web service to a client. What is the problem of having a huge control flow graph?

Comment: But yes, you _could_ use ANTLR to parse Java source files. But that would be just ~0.01% of the total effort needed to create something like this. It'd be like answering "yes" to the question _"can I use a text editor to create an app that creates a CFG from any given Java application?"_.

Comment: @Joeblackdev, there's no problem. Just a lot of work. :)

Comment: Ok. I don't have an awful lot of time to do something like this. My main objective is to be able to parse a java source file, such that I can build up a control flow graph. After doing this, I would like to be able to traverse the control flow graph (backwards) from a particular statement in the graph to retrieve all of the other code that may affect it. Not sure where to even begin ... :(

Comment: @Joeblackdev: what you want is called a "program slicer" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_slicing. You will find that after you parse a Java file, there's a huge step called "name resolution" that you will need before you can do serious control flow analysis (otherwise, which function does o.foo(x) call?). You'd best look for a solution that provides parsing and name resolution as a minimum.

Comment: @Ira Baxter, a slicer is exactly what I want. I have looked at indus, but that uses java 1.4. I need use java 1.6. I have looked at 'staticslicer' on sourceforge (http://sourceforge.net/projects/someslice/), however there is no in-depth documentation to say how this was done, or how the control-flow graph was built. As far as I know, there are no slicers out there that can help me.

Comment: @Joeblackdev: if you really want a slicer, you'll need local and global data flow analysis built on top of that control flow graph. You really don't want to do this, unless you are doing this as a real product. (We have pretty much all the machinery necessary to do this as part of the DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit, and are building C and COBOL slicers; a Java slicer is not presently in our plans). What do you intend to do with a slicer?

Comment: With the slicer, I want to calculate a static backwards slice from a slicing criterion. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be anything around that does this, so it looks like I will have to 'try' and do this myself. Just not sure how to go about it to be honest.

Comment: @Joeblackdev: you have everything you need listed in the abstract above in the comments. What's left is tons of sweat (one reason you don't see these as COTS is because it does take tons of sweat).  I was interested in what you would do if you could compute the (backward) slice.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but im still totally lost. I might just abandon this approach completely. Do you know of any algorithms for traversing a control flow graph if I even manage to build one?

Comment: @Joeblackdev: There's a ton of literature on compiler-like control and data flow analysis out there, including standard texts such as Aho and Ullman's Compiler book.  Those type of books will tell you how to parse, how to build symbol tables, how to build control and data flow graphs.  There are no books on slicers but a lot of papers (Google "program slicer" or read the wikipedia-reference articles).  Finally, you need some kind of UI to render the "slice" so you can see without getting drowned by the 2 million other lines of you application....

Comment: @Joeblackdev: .... What the generic technology papers don't do is help you deal with the Java langauge beast itself.  Knowing precisely how control flow happens (what if you get an exception in a constructor on a super call?) and how names are looked up (generics make this really fun) is critical to getting to this right.  The effort to do all of this is actually pretty high. the reason for you to do this is because you desperately want to know how, or you want to become a player in tools in this space.  The reason to let somebody else do it is so you can have a life.

Comment: @Joeblackdev:  There are people that do this.  (e.g. my company, because we want to become a player in this space; we've got well over a man-year in getting Java name and type resolution in place for the various dialects of Java, and we have IMHO astonishingly good foundation machinery on which to build such tools, see my bio. For all that, we do not yet have a Java slicer, and probably won't for another year due to all that other stuff you need).  The learning curve is long and hard, and time to do it is long.  Yes, it appears to be a really attractive idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to use to Soot framework. That contains all of the provisions I need to perform control flow graph analysis.

Comment: This is a good start, in that Soot uses (IIRC) the class files to provide essentially the name lookup data.   You'll still have to extract the CFG, and I think you'll still have to compute the data flows, compute the slice, and render it all in some usable form.  Still quite a lot of work.  Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't worked with Antlr, but I used for a similar purpose the [ASM bytecode manipulation framework](http://asm.ow2.org/). There are probably more straightforward ways, but if you want to have a really tailored solution, ASM is worth a look! Moreover, the documentation of ASM is comprehensive.

Comment: Thanks for this. Did you find this gave you a complete control flow graph which accounted for exceptions as well?

Comment: My solution didn't include exceptions though it is also possible to support them. A good start is the [PDF documentation](http://download.forge.objectweb.org/asm/asm-guide.pdf). But be aware that a solution based on the ASM framework may require quite an effort, especially if you aren't familiar with Java bytecode.

Comment: what is JastAdd? Would it be a better option that ASM? Thanks

Comment: Some fellow students recommended it, however I used ASM cause I found the documentation was better (back then). I think possibly the flow analysis tool (available on [this page](http://jastadd.org/web/jastaddj/extensions.php) is useful for you. A publication about this matter is available [here](http://bit.ly/mpgxYr).